# redirect to a new wpf window after 10 seconds?

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, window, wpf-controls

How to redirect to a new WPF `Window` after 10 seconds?I am trying to use `Windows.Hide()` for current `Window` and `Windows.Show()` for another `Window` but this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you put your code for the transition into your question?

Comment: I want to redirect from MainWindow.xaml to Window1.xaml after 10 seconds.I wrote the code below.                                  Window1 w = new Window1();
            InitializeComponent();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            this.Hide();
            w.Show();

Comment: In the case above MainWindow doesnt appear at all and Window1 appears after 10 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MainWindow doesn't have a chance to finish its construction.  You can change your code to this, or something similar...

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindowLoaded;
    }
    void MainWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= MainWindowLoaded;
        Window1 window1 = new Window1();
        window1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((SendOrPostCallback) delegate
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                Hide();
                window1.Show();
            }, new object[] {null});
    }
```

This lets the first window finish it's construction.

Comment: Thanks Garry this works fine the only prob is I have an animation on my MainWindow page which doesn't work because of Thread.Sleep().Can you suggest something for this.

Comment: Yes, you'll probably want to take the code here and move it into a background worker.  It's best to create a totally new question about wpf background workers and animations because this one is about redirection and it's a good question the way it is...

Comment: System.Threading namespace is required for SendOrPostCallback delegate.

Answer (score 4):

I used a timer for this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{            
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();                            

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();                                
     }

     private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        Window1 w = new Window1();
        this.Hide();
        w.Show();

        dispatcherTimer.Stop();               
     }
}
```